# changing bound method behaviour dynamically

Tags: python

I have created an instace of a anonymous class as follows:

```
msg = type("Inner", (object,), {"MessageType": lambda self: "300","Feed": lambda self:{} })()
```

When I print out Feed it seems fine:

```
>>> msg.Feed()
{}
```

Now I need Feed to return a different value for this instance:

```
>>> msg.Feed={"A":1}
>>> msg.Feed()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    msg.Feed()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
>>>
```

How would this work?

Comment: You set `msg.Feed` to a dictionary. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before, `Feed` was a function, which is callable. Then you replaced `Feed` with a `dict`. A `dict` is not callable; if you want to replace it with a callable function that returns a `dict`, use another `lambda`:

```
msg.Feed = lambda: {"A": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class you've described here, the "Feed" method is a function that just returns an empty dict.

When you assign to it:

```
msg.Feed={"A":1}
```

It becomes an actual dict, instead of a function, so when you try to call it again:

```
msg.Feed()
```

You're actually saying this:

```
{"A":1}()
```

And a dict is not callable, hence the exception.